# Uploading a file via Perl using POST and encoding it as multipart/form-data while also maintaining API key in header

Tags: api, rest, perl, upload, lwp

```
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://www.x/files/';

my $file = x.exe;
my $api = 'x';

my $req = $ua->post($url,
  'x-apikey' => $api, 
  Content_Type => 'form-data',
  Content => 'file' => [ $file ],
  );
  print $req->content;
```

I have tried numerous examples and have had no luck uploading anything. I generally get errors relating to the lack of file, hell I have even gotten a literal 404 error. The API works perfectly in every other aspect, I just cannot figure out how to upload a file.

The code posted above, without the api key and on a different website works fine with uploading a file.
What am I doing wrong with respect to adding the API key in the header? I feel its obvious.

**Solution:**

```
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://www.x/files'; #should not have had a trailing /

my $file = 'x.exe';

my $req = $ua->post($url,
'x-apikey' => 'x',
'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
'Content' => [file => [$file] ],
  );
  print $req->content;
```

Looks like it was a mixture of typo's and bad formatting. Sorry guys!

Comment: `Content => 'file' => [ $file ]` (`Content => 'file', [ $file ] => undef`) makes no sense. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!